# How to use java empty HashSet in if-statement?

Tags: java, if-statement, data-structures, set, hashset

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, HashSet<String>> test = new HashMap<String, HashSet<String>>();

    test.put("1", new HashSet<String>());
    System.out.println(test);

    System.out.println(test.get("1"));

    if(test.get("1") == null){
        System.out.println("Hello world");
    }
}
```

The first println gets me `{1=[]}`
The second one gets me `[]`
I am trying to print out "Hello world" but the if statement isn't going through.
Is the empty HashSet, `[]` not equal to `null`?

How do I use the empty HashSet in this if statement?

Comment: Is not having a bag (`null`) the same as having an empty bag (empty `HashSet`)? (Note: I'm using the real-world meaning of "bag" here, not the data structure.)

Comment: In Java, `==` on two objects (i.e. not primitives) **always** compares to see if they are references to the same object (or are both null).  Some languages have the ability to redefine `==` in some cases so that it compares the contents.  Java does not.  (Java normally uses `equals()` to compare contents, but that won't help you here because `equals()` on a `HashSet` does not consider an empty set to be equal to a null reference.  They could have defined it that way, but they didn't.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a difference between `null`, which means "nothing at all," and an empty `HashSet`. An empty `HashSet` is an actual `HashSet`, but one that just coincidentally happens to not have any elements in it. This is similar to how `null` is not the same as the empty string `""`, which is a string that has no characters in it.

To check if the `HashSet` is empty, use the `isEmpty` method:

```
if(test.get("1").isEmpty()){
    System.out.println("Hello world");
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 5):

> Is the empty `HashSet`, `[]` not equal to `null`?

Correct, it is not. This is precisely the reason your code behaves the way it does.

To check for both `null` and empty set, use the following construct:

```
HashSet<String> set = test.get("1");
if (set == null || set.isEmpty()) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The empty `HashSet` isn't a `null`. Add a test by using the [`HashSet.size()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#size%28%29)

```
if (test.get("1") == null || test.get("1").size() == 0) {
```

or use [`HashSet.isEmpty()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#isEmpty%28%29),

```
if (test.get("1") == null || test.get("1").isEmpty()) {
```

Alternatively, you could comment out

```
// test.put("1", new HashSet<String>());
System.out.println(test);
```

Then `test.get("1")` is ***null***.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the Set_Obj.isEmpty() method. This returns a boolean value checking if the set has any element in it (true).